# Kubernetes single deployment yaml file for spinning up the application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am setting up kubernetes for an application with 8 microservices,activemq,postgres,redis and mongodb.

After the entire configuration of pods and deployment ,is there any way to create a single master deployment yaml file which will create the entire set of services,replcas etc for the entire application.

Note:I will be using multiple deployment yaml files,statefulsets etc for all above mentioned services.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:kubernetes-helm]; do you have a Helm chart, checked into source control?  That's a good source of truth for what objects should exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
NAMESPACE="your_namespace"
RESOURCES="configmap secret daemonset deployment service hpa"

for resource in ${RESOURCES};do
  rsrcs=$(kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} get -o json ${resource}|jq '.items[].metadata.name'|sed "s/\"//g")
  for r in ${rsrcs};do
    dir="${NAMESPACE}/${resource}"
    mkdir -p "${dir}"
    kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} get -o yaml ${resource} ${r} > "${dir}/${r}.yaml"
  done
done
```

Remember to specify what resources you want exported in the script.

[More info here](https://gist.github.com/negz/c3ee465b48306593f16c523a22015bec)

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any way to create a single master deployment yaml file which will create the entire set of services,replicas etc for the entire application.**

Since you already mentioned `kubernetes-helm` why don't you actually used it for that exact purpose? In short helm is sort of package manager for Kubernetes, some say similar to yum or apt. It deploys charts which you can actually refer to as packed application. Its pack of all your pre-configured applications which can be deploy as one unit. It's not entirely one file but more collection of files that build so called helm chart.

**What are the helm charts?**

Well they are basically K8s yaml manifest combined into a single package that can be installed to your cluster. And installing the package is just as simple as running single command such as `helm install`. Once done the charts are highly reusable which reduces the time for creating dev, test and prod environments.

As an example of a complex helm chart deploying multiple resources you many want to check [Stackstorm](https://github.com/StackStorm/stackstorm-ha).
Basically once deployed without any custom config this chart will deploy 2 replicas for each component of StackStorm as well as backends like RabbitMQ, MongoDB and Redis.